# SQL Server access to old data that has backed up and not available in current version

Tags: sql-server

I have a UI that users can search IDs of students. The current database contains student data for the last **2 years**, and data before that has been "FULL" backed up in some files in which saved in some name format that contains date, like **backup_db_2017_01_to_2018_01**.

Currently when the user searches for an old student ID:
I search the current database and if there is no data, it automatically restores the last backup and merges data with the current database. If the id is not in the last backup, it restored another backup, and so on...
In this way, too much data merged with current data and it takes too long time. In the worst scenario, the student id is in the oldest backup.
I wonder what is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you have the space to RESTORE and MEREGE all of the old backups?

You could consider merging all of the old data onto a READ-ONLY FILEGROUP so that it is always available but not able to be updated.

Comment: You mean the read-only filegroup is separated from my current data?

Comment: That was a good idea, Thanks a lot. Is it ok to ask a vote up for my question?